# I attach, I am attaching, or I have attached

Tags: grammar, tenses, email

So I got into this discussion with my German colleague about what's the proper way to write a particular sentence in an internal work email. I would really appreciate it if you could explain why any particular approach is correct or incorrect.

Her email had two attachments. One with and one without mark-ups.

What she had initially written:

> I attach a clean version and a mark-up of the document

What I thought was correct

> I've attached a clean and a marked-up version of the document

What I also thought was correct

> I'm attaching a clean and a marked-up version of the document

What she finally wrote

> I've attached a clean version and a mark-up of the document

Here are my questions:

- Which of these sentences are correct?
- What's the appropriate tense when it comes to attachments? Attach/Attached/Attaching
- Is "mark-up of the document" correct or is "marked-up version of the document" correct?
- Can you please explain why?

Comment: Arguably, any of them are correct, but I think the first version ("I attach") sounds very pretentious. Think of a posh person with a monocle and excellent British-like articulation: 'I [hereby] attach a clean version...'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"I attach" seems an awkward construction. Many people (especially Indians) use "I am attaching" but I think the best option is "I have attached" because you have already attached it!  Both 'mark-up' and 'marked up version' mean the same though mark-up is simpler and 'marked up version' is more formal. In any case, even work related emails offer great flexibility of language, and the main intention is to make yourself understood clearly!

Comment: *I attach; I am attaching & I have attached* work equally well. Suit yourself.

Comment: Right. As I said, even work related emails offer great flexibility of language, and the main intention is to make yourself understood clearly!

Comment: In formal letter writing we used to write sentences like "I attach a copy of the document in question", "I am attaching a copy of the bill for your kind reference", "please find attached a list of the items ordered for", etc; but for some reason, "I have attached" was rarely used. Now that emails are the currency of business correspondence, it is interesting that 'I have attached the pdf file" seems somehow more appropriate, if only because "attaching a file" is a specific task that is completed before sending the email!